# Recursive async-await callback with window.location.reload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await

I'm `await`ing some API callback that return 401 response with a logout callback and redirect to login page. But, it keep doing window.location.reload on the logout callback because the API is called again and again in the previous page. What can I do so I can get around this?

```js
try {
        // Run all actions here that needed to be executed at first
        await this.someMethods()
        await this.someMethods()
        await this.someMethods()
        await this.someMethods()
        await this.someMethods()
      } catch (error) {
        // Check for login session
        const response = Object.assign({}, error)
        if (response.response.status === 401 || response.response.status === 401) {
          AuthService.logout() //LOGOUT CALLBACK
          this.$toasted.show('Season Expired!. Please Re-Login', {
            position: 'top-center',
            duration: 2500,
            type: 'error'
          })
        }
      }
```

```js
logout () {
    window.localStorage.clear()
    window.location.reload(true)
    router.push('/login')
  }
```

Comment: What's the point of the reload? Notice that `router.push('/login')` won't be executed after you have left the page. Maybe you meant `window.location.replace('/login')`?

Comment: @Bergi simple solution for resetting vuex state

Comment: Well, looks like the wrong solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need to use Promise.all

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```

here is your example

```
try {
        // Run all actions here that needed to be executed at first
        await Promise.all([this.someMethods1() , this.someMethods2() ,this.someMethods3()]) ;

      } catch (error) {
        // Check for login session
        const response = Object.assign({}, error)
        if (response.response.status === 401 || response.response.status === 401) {
          AuthService.logout() //LOGOUT CALLBACK
          this.$toasted.show('Season Expired!. Please Re-Login', {
            position: 'top-center',
            duration: 2500,
            type: 'error'
          })
        }
      }
```

In this way the error block will be entering only once

Comment: I'll look up to these solution. I've some cases with these but need to try it first